# Rxjs mergeMap: Concat 2 related Api Requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, mergemap

I have two api requests, the second one depends on the first one. The first request gets an array of 3 facilities. After this i need to do an api request for each facility to get an image which i need. I need the uuid of the facilities. I thought this could be easy with mergeMap.
But i have 2 problems and can't find a solution: inside merge map, i thought service will be one service of the array but it is the whole array. Also I need to subscribe to getImage() too and store the value inside service.image.

```
getNewestNursingServices() {
  return this.http.get('api/nursing-service/newest').pipe(
   mergeMap(service => this.getImage('PREVIEW', service.uuid))
  );
}
getImage(type: string, nursingService: string): Observable<Image> {
  return this.http.get<Image>('api/nursing-images/' + type + '/' + nursingService);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` or `concat`:

```
getNewestNursingServices() {
  return this.http.get('api/nursing-service/newest').pipe(
   mergeMap((service: any[]) => {
     return concat(...service.map(s => {
       return this.getImage('PREVIEW', s.uuid)
     }) 
   }) 
  );
}
```

Comment: I would advise `switchMap` and `forkJoin`/`combineLatest`.

Comment: Agree that `forkJoin` / `combineLatest` **might** be a better option, but for `siwtchMap` I couldn't agree. On every `getNewestNursingServices` invocation, new source is created, so cancellation wouldn't happen anyway and `mergeMap` is a lighter operator

Comment: It's just that switchMap sounds much better suited. Maybe sometimes you swap the http call for a Subject, now the logic doesn't suit the needs. I'd still use switchMap

Comment: `switchMap` throws away the results of ongoing request, if another event comes from upstream. That suits the well known search-as-you-type problem, but here the OP wanted the result of all requests.

Comment: Well, agree that its debatable @ritaj :)

Comment: @Alex Biro - there is no upstream, just a function call which creates a new stream every time. So no cancellation of the previous would happen

Comment: "All requests" is just one. And the function is called "newest" services, discarding *older* services sounds exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius that's correct, it wouldn't matter here, but the point of `switchMap` is that it cancels the ongoing request, so if you don't rely on it, I think you should not use `switchMap`. But agree, this is a bit subjective.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got the question right.

So your first problem was that the first api call returns an array. That can be solved by `mergeMap`-ing the flattened array, so the downstream observable will emit the 3 services consecutively.

```js
getNewestNursingServices() {
  return this.http.get('api/nursing-service/newest')
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((services: []) => {
        // `of` will return an observable which emits the items of the array after each other
        return of(services);
      }),
      mergeMap(service => this.getImage('PREVIEW', service.uuid)),
      tap((image: Image) => {
        // here you can do sideeffects with the images, eg. pushing them into an array somewhere...
      }),
      reduce(
        (allImages: Image[], currentImage: Image) => {
          // ... or you can collect them into an array, so the downstream will be `Observable<Image[]>`
          allImages.push(currentImage);
          return allImages;
        },
        [],
      ),
    );
}
```

Regarding the fact that you have to subscribe, that's not true, you can use the resulting observable for example in an `async` pipe, if you don't want to do the sideeffect+subscription pattern.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: The other answer is much better.

Comment: @ritaj I am open to any improvement suggestion. In what way is the other solution better?